# error in save date in database with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, insert

want to be able to store the current date  from PHP in to a mysql table.

```
$date = sprintf("%'04s-%'02s-%'02s",$year_number,$month_number,$day_number);

$sql="INSERT INTO  `prg omran`.`paid`(`Comapny_id`,`Amount`,`Date`,`Creditrecord`) VALUES ('".$ID."','".$credit."','".$date."','".$yes."')";
```

Date's column type in database is DATE.

but date save in database like this: 0000-00-00

help me.

Comment: what you get if `echo $date` ?

Comment: interesting unless you dont pass a bad date format or date in mysql `DATE` field it never becomes 0000-00-00

Comment: i don't get your mean

Comment: I assume the date filed is having datatype as DATE and if you pass some bad date format while saving it will add as 0000-00-00 now to debug this echo the query and paste it directly on mysql and see what happens you will also see how the values are enclosed in the query.

Comment: Can you show what `echo $sql` says?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the current date, just use one of the [built-in MySQL functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) for that:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO  `prg omran`.`paid`(`Comapny_id`,`Amount`,`Date`,`Creditrecord`) 
VALUES ('".$ID."','".$credit."',curdate(),'".$yes."')";
```

You won't ever have to worry about formatting or any sort of funny inputs and you can still do all sorts of addition, subtraction and the like using one of the many other functions.

Edit: I have just looked up [some information on the date system](https://www.fourmilab.ch/documents/calendar/) and you will run into problems trying to squeeze that data into a date field. The first six months have 31 days, the next 5 have 30 days, then the last has 29 - unless it is a leap year in which case it has 30. The date field simply won't LET you insert these values into a date field.

You might need to convert your data to a timestamp and write a function to encode/decode it into the format you need.

Comment: i can't use this function because i want to save persian (farsi) date

Comment: @Neda I have added (what I think is) an interesting edit/addition to my answer.

Comment: Where has he said that he's putting invalid dates into the date field?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$date = sprintf("%'04s-%'02s-%'02s",$year_number,$month_number,$day_number);

$sql="INSERT INTO  `prg omran`.`paid`(`Comapny_id`,`Amount`,`Date`,`Creditrecord`) VALUES      ('".$ID."','".$credit."',".$date.",'".$yes."')";
```

or

if you want to inset today's date use

```
$sql="INSERT INTO  `prg omran`.`paid`(`Comapny_id`,`Amount`,`Date`,`Creditrecord`) 
VALUES ('".$ID."','".$credit."',curdate(),'".$yes."')";
```

Comment: i can't use this function because i want to save persian (farsi) date

Comment: This won't work -- you need to put the date in quotes in the SQL.

Comment: i think in your sql query '".$date."' this becomes as error use this as ".$date.".

Answer (score 0):

I need to store Date field in database for example VARCHAR(10) becouse, DATE type in mysql server don't support persian (farsi) date.